# Unity Missing Override Button

Tags: unity-game-engine, overriding

I cannot see override button in the Inspector menu for Player Prefab.

How can i make it appeared on the menu?

[image: The screenshot of my Unity screen]

Answer (score 0):

You already are in [Prefab Edit mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingInPrefabMode.html) so any changes are applied right away!

The override Dropdown only appears if

- you are in the normal scene mode and have an [Instance Override](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrefabInstanceOverrides.html) of your prefab asset directly in the scene level
- your prefab is a [Variant](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrefabVariants.html) of another prefab
- your prefab is a [Nested Prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NestedPrefabs.html) instance under another prefab.

You can exit the prefab edit mode by clicking on the `<` arrow at the top of the `Hierarchy` window next to `Player`.